# Scroll to top after clicking page 2 in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

When you have products split on multiple pages in WooCommerce, it loads the next paage from the bottom. Because I have lazyload on images this means for a while there is just an empty white page. I would like to move to the top when the next page is loaded.

My code doesn't work. I have tried the following in my functions.php:

```html
<?php if (isset($_GET['swoof'])): ?>

    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".woof_products_top_panel_content").offset().top - 100
                }, 777);
            }, 333);

        });
    </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution related to your question. that solution works on all pages.
Add the below code in your **function.php**.

```
function move_to_top_on_pagination() {
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $(document.body).on('click', '.page-numbers:not(.current)', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".woof_products_top_panel_content").offset().top - 100
                }, 777);
                var link = $(this).attr('href');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href = link;
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'move_to_top_on_pagination');
```

Here I have set the timeout to 1 sec so you can change it as per your site speed.